# What is this texture called?

Tags: fabric

[image: two pieces of jersey fabric, black and red, with white specks]
What is this type of texture on a fabric called? I've seen knit fabrics with these tiny specks with a contrasting colour.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Nep

> Generally, a nep is defined as an entanglement of fibers, that can be caused by environmental factors during growth, processing or are inherent to particular varieties.

[image: Polyester nep]

[abtexintl.net](http://www.abtexintl.net/)

[image]

[hm.com](https://www2.hm.com/en_gb/productpage.0542743012.html)

[image]

[indiamart.com](https://www.indiamart.com/proddetail/neps-melange-knitted-fabric-17030043155.html)

[image]

[taylorstitch.com](https://www.taylorstitch.com/products/the-glacier-shirt-in-navy-nep-twill)

[image: NEP YARN]

[asos.com](https://www.asos.com/au/sisley/sisley-scoop-neck-t-shirt-with-nep-yarn/prd/5667406)

### Fleck Nep

[image]
[superdenim.com](https://www.superdenim.com/eu/joe-mccoy-freck-nep-trousers-black-mp17103.html)

[image]
[realmccoyslondon.com](https://www.realmccoyslondon.com/eu/fleck-nep-open-collar-shirt.html)

### Flecked Corduroy

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can often see a similar, but unintended effect on knitwear called [pilling](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pill_(textile)). This is a defect of the fabric caused by washing and wear. Small, loose fibres on the surface become felted in these small pills.